# sqoop export fails to load data into mysql from hive warehouse folder

Tags: mysql, export, hive, bigdata, sqoop

sqoop export fails with error.

my export command is:
`sqoop export --connect jdbc:mysql://<ip>:3306/<database> --username user --password pass --verbose --table <table name> --export-dir <dir in hdfs>`

fields are terminated by hive default delimiter.

error message:

```
15/01/12 08:50:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id :     attempt_201412261920_1440_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:757)
at <tablename>.__loadFromFields(<tablename>.java:418)
at <tablename>.parse(<tablename>.java:332)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:81)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.TextExportMapper.map(TextExportMapper.java:40)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
at com.cloudera.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:189)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:270)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1177)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:264)`
```

Comment: It looks like your username/password are not getting authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the mistake.. It was bcz of column mismatch from hive and mysql tables. Now it is working good.

Comment: what kind of mismatch column?

Comment: This is an old post because of which I don't remember exact mismatch at the moment. If I am not wrong it was because we had more fields in destination mysql table than what was available in the HDFS file.